# How to use counter with odbc transaction in C#

Tags: c#, transactions, odbc, counter

How to implement counter, so that it commit multiple queries, for example every 1000 "queries". Problem is that with or without transaction query is executed by "ExecuteNonQuery()" and it execute one by one, not as I whant e.g. every 1000?

```
        odbc.dbsqlite.Open();
        odbc.dbkopito.Open();


        OdbcCommand comlite = odbc.dbsqlite.CreateCommand();
        OdbcCommand comkopit = odbc.dbkopito.CreateCommand();
        OdbcTransaction transaction = null;

        comkopit.CommandText =
            "SELECT DISTINCT ... "

        #region TRY
        try
        {
            OdbcDataReader dbKopitReader = comkopit.ExecuteReader();

            var ordinal = new
            {
                cenik = dbKopitReader.GetOrdinal("sifra"),
                ident = dbKopitReader.GetOrdinal("ident"),
                klasifikacija = dbKopitReader.GetOrdinal("klasifikacija"),
                cena = dbKopitReader.GetOrdinal("cena"),
                eankoda = dbKopitReader.GetOrdinal("eankoda"),
            };

            int stevec = 0;

            while (dbKopitReader.Read())
            {
                var cena = Convert.ToDouble(dbKopitReader.GetDouble(ordinal.cena));
                var ident = Convert.ToString(dbKopitReader.GetString(ordinal.ident));
                var cenik = Convert.ToString(dbKopitReader.GetString(ordinal.cenik));
                var klasi = Convert.ToString(dbKopitReader.GetString(ordinal.klasifikacija));
                var eanko = Convert.ToString(dbKopitReader.GetString(ordinal.eankoda));

                using (var cmd = odbc.dbsqlite.CreateCommand() )
                {
                    try
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO ARTIKLI (KLASIFIKACIJA, CENA, BARKODA, CENIK, IDENT) " +
                                          "VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";

                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KLASIFIKACIJA", klasi);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CENA", cena);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BARKODA", eanko);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CENIK", cenik);
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IDENT", ident);

                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        if (stevec % 1000 == 0)
                        {
                            transaction.Commit();
                            transaction = odbc.dbsqlite.BeginTransaction();
                            cmd.Transaction = transaction;
                        }
                        stevec++;

                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                        try
                        {
                            transaction.Rollback();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Transakcija ni aktivna");                               
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            comlite.Dispose();
            odbc.dbsqlite.Close();

            dbKopitReader.Close();
            comkopit.Dispose();
            odbc.dbkopito.Close();
```

Comment: Add full example code (with loop and so on). Your transaction will be committed on first run because 0 % 1000 is equal to 0.

Comment: @Reniuz - added full example of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Transaction is not initiated at first iteration (should get null exception).
2. Transaction is not assigned to command.
3. You creating transaction and assigning it to command every 1000th, but next 999 commands is created without transactions.
4. You committing transaction on very first iteration.

Here is example how your code should look like:

```
var transaction = odbc.dbsqlite.BeginTransaction();
int count = 0;
while(read)
{
  count++;
  if(count % 1000 == 0)
  {
     transaction.Commit();
     transaction = odbc.dbsqlite.BeginTransaction();
  }
  //I imagine this CreateCommand() is assigning connection...
  using(var cmd = odbc.dbsqlite.CreateCommand())
  {
     cmd.CommandText = "INSERT...";
     //Params...
     cmd.Transaction = transaction;
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
}
```